Error when using create function of Pytchat library for specific video IDs in a Heroku server
My web app uses Pytchat module once a day to retrieve YouTube live stream information, but about 1 out of every 60 video IDs fail to retrieve, and this issue only occurs on Heroku.
I've searched extensively for common factors among the videos that cause errors with the YouTube API, but I couldn't find any.
Here is my environment:

Python 3.12.4
Pytchat 0.5.5(latest)

Here is my script:
import pytchat
import requests, json

# Check if the API communication works
url = requests.get("http://api.aoikujira.com/kawase/json/usd")
text = url.text
json_currency = json.loads(text)
print(json_currency)
print("Successful in API communication")

ids = "g5vKkS19nq8,kHo37taBFP8,6IJpVVGIxno,LPI_FnuvfhE,dWhmdgpeBts,NXcmsY5iXkw,ECATLuOt1AE"
ids = ids.split(",")

# To view the error, please run this code in heroku server.
# chat = pytchat.create(video_id=ids[0],interruptable=False)

# Try to create pytchat objects with wrong ids
for id in ids:
    try:
        chat = pytchat.create(video_id=id,interruptable=False)
        print("Successful in create")
    except:
        print("Failed in create")

Here is the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pytchat/util/__init__.py", line 107, in get_channelid
    raise IndexError
IndexError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/test_script/mini_livetest.py", line 15, in <module>
    chat = pytchat.create(video_id=ids[0],interruptable=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pytchat/core/__init__.py", line 7, in create
    return PytchatCore(_vid, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pytchat/core/pytchat.py", line 96, in __init__
    self._setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pytchat/core/pytchat.py", line 106, in _setup
    channel_id=util.get_channelid(self._client, self._video_id),
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pytchat/util/__init__.py", line 110, in get_channelid
    ret = get_channelid_2nd(client, video_id)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pytchat/util/__init__.py", line 119, in get_channelid_2nd
    raise InvalidVideoIdException(f"Cannot find channel id for video id:{video_id}. This video id seems to be invalid.")
pytchat.exceptions.InvalidVideoIdException: Cannot find channel id for video id:g5vKkS19nq8. This video id seems to be invalid.

The code worked not only in local, but also in colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1npGihQ4KVHFn1tBMpAbY7HDFVsDk4CNW
